# Add an item/value inside object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How i add an item inside object in array?

My array(res.users):

```
{userName: "name", email: "email@email.com"}
```

I want:

```
{userName: "name", email: "email@email.com", access: "admin"}
```

I tried:

```
array.push(Object.assign(res.users, {'access': 'admin' }))
```

My return:

```
[
    {userName: "name", email: "email@email.com"},
    access: 'admin'
]
```

**Demo:**

```js
const res = {userName: "name", email: "email@email.com"}, array = [];
array.push(Object.assign(res, {'access': 'admin'}))
console.log( array )
```

Edit: res.users is an array, i had written wrong

Comment: `obj.access = "admin"`

Comment: I'm guessing `res.users` is not actually the object you're showing, but rather an array, like `[{userName: "name", email: "email@email.com"}]`

Comment: `res.users` appears to be an array, so not what you think it is. Or what you said “my object” was, anyway.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine as seen in the demo if `res.users` is actually an object as you have mentioned.

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake, res.users is an array

Comment: Not according to what you posted. It's an object. Arrays in JavaScript have numeric indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `obj.access = "admin"`:

```js
let obj = {userName: "name", email: "email@email.com"}

obj.access = "admin"

console.log(obj)
```